# Does Motion 3.2.12 support RTSP MJPEG

Tags: linux, video-streaming, ip-camera, motion

I hav a Zavio P6210 IP camera (http://www.zavio.com/product.php?id=85) which supports RTSP. My settings on the camera are : (profile1)

- encoding : MJPEG
- resolution : 640 x 1180
- Maximum fps : 30
- quality : standard

Authentication is disabled on my camera. 
In /etc/motion/motion.conf I've set the netcam_url to rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/video.pro1

When I pass this URL into VLC Media Player, the stream works fine. 
However, when I start motion, I always get this error messages :

```
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3482368 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3478785
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[1] Thread 1 started
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.12 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8080
[1] Invalid netcam_url (rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/video.pro1)
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8081
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] Invalid netcam_url (rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/video.pro1)
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
[1] Invalid netcam_url (rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/video.pro1)
```

I don't have a clue how to fix this error. Does Motion 3.2.12 not support RTSP MJPEG or am J making a mistake somewhere ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to point to `8080` port in `netcam_url`

Comment: I've  set the RTSP port in the camera to 8080 and changed the 'netcam_URL' to rtsp://192.168.1.52:8080/video.pro1 in motion, unfortunately without any succes

Answer (score 0):

rtsp will be native and stable in motion one day, you can already compile a non official rtsp compatible motion version from github, I didn't try, I like distro packages, work is in progress on this for some time now, until this day I wrote and use a simple rtsp2jpeg snapshot virtual camera php wrapper script, so I can use rtsp only cameras as classic jpeg snapshot based cameras.

Use it as if it was a jpeg snapshot url.
for each request It uses ffmpeg to grab a snapshot from a rtsp stream, writes it to ram, pushes it to the requesting client and deletes it

It also crops the image so that motion is happy with a real modulo 16 almost full hd resolution, may be you wont need it, depends, I do need it only on one of my full hd cam.

U will certainly have to tweak the ffmpeg command as needed to work with your camera ...

```
<?php

$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true))->format("Ymd-Hisu");

$imagepath="/var/run/shm/cam7-$now-".mt_rand().".jpg";

exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i "rtsp://192.168.1.7:554/user=user&password=iwonttellu&channel=1&stream=0.sdp" -f image2 -vframes 1 -vf "crop=1920:1072:0:4" '.$imagepath);

if (file_exists($imagepath)) {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($imagepath));
    readfile($imagepath);
    unlink($imagepath);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

?>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you would need MrDave's motion(`motionmrdave`). To save time you might want to first backup your current `motion config file(s)`. Once done then remove your existing "`motion`" installation.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:motionmrdave/motion
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install motion -y
```

Restore the motion config file(s). Restart `motion` and your `RTSP` should work fine.